# MongoDB Update Operation and Read Preference

Tags: php, mongodb

If I issue an update to mongodb with a read preference of MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY is it possible for my update operation to read an out of date record for determining which records to update?

To be clear I'm basically asking is update considered a write operation and therefore follows "Secondardy - A replica set member that replicates the contents of the master database. Secondary members may handle read requests, but only the primary members can handle write operations. See Secondaries"

So if mongo decides to split the operation into two separate components, the query portion to locate the records to update and the write portion, the read COULD read out of date data from a secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not split the query from the update. All the MongoDB drivers use the MongoDB wire protocol to send and receive data to and from the mongo instances they are connected to. Updates, Inserts, Queries and Deletes have different OpCodes and formats. The OpCodes OP_UPDATE, OP_INSERT and OP_DELETE all identify their payload as being changes to data and will always route to the primary and will take into account the write preference. OpCode OP_QUERY will use the read preference.

More detail on the wire protocol here: http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/

Comment: If I could bother you for a follow up, given what you've stated I don't understand how the following could happen.

"Use Unique Indexes
WARNING
To avoid inserting the same document more than once, only use upsert: true if the query field is uniquely indexed.
Given a collection named people where no documents have a name field that holds the value Andy. Consider when multiple clients issue the following update with an upsert parameter at the same time"

Comment: That is from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

It seems the update is very clearly reading from an out of date source otherwise it would not upsert twice from two clients?

Comment: No it's a timing issue - client1 reads and sees no customer with the name Andy and it get's ready to insert - this is not an atomic operation. client1 yields to client2 prior to the insert phase, client2 reads and sees no Andy so it too prepares an insert. It yields to client1 which inserts successfully and then client2 which fails. The issue has to do with updates not being atomic, not that the read is out of date - it's not at the time of the read, it's just before the insert phase the doc changes. For this use case you should use FindAndModify which is atomic.

Comment: I don't find any keywords `primary`, `route` or `replica` in your [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) , from where you get the messages about replica route with different operations?